# Get the value of checked checkbox in the form of unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to set the values of checked checkbox in the form of `unordered` list that is in `ul li`. From my function the values are printed like `<ul><li>100</li></ul>`. In this function i am getting the values but not printing in list form. Please help me out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[name=coffee]").click(function() {
    myFunction();
  });

  function myFunction() {
    var total = "<ul>";
    $("[name=coffee]:checked").each(function() {
      total += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
    });

    total += "</ul>";
    alert(total);
    $("#demo").text(total);

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>

  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.html`, not the `.text` of the element, so that what you inserted is interpreted as HTML markup, not as text:

```js
$("[name=coffee]").click(function() {
  var total = "<ul>";
  $("[name=coffee]:checked").each(function() {
    total += "<li>" + $(this).val() + "</li>";
  });
  total += "</ul>";
  $("#demo").html(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>How would you like your coffee?</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="100">With cream<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="150">With sugar<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="200">With milk<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="coffee" value="250">With tea<br>
  <br>

  <input type="text" id="order" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```